# Set up Nlog for seq programmably

Tags: c#, nlog, seq

I need to write on code configuration of Nlog, instead of the nlog.config which sends log to seq server, on C#.
I didn't understand which library of Nlog should I use to do it. I have been trying several options, but it didn't work to me.
the nlog.config code is mentioned below:

```
  <targets>
      <target name="seq" xsi:type="BufferingWrapper" bufferSize="1000" 
         flushTimeout="2000">
       <target xsi:type="Seq" serverUrl="http://localhost:5341" apiKey="" />
       </target>
   </targets>
   <rules>
     <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="seq" />
    </rules>
```

I will be happy if you write the full code needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my Nlog configurator if i can't use the XML file

Define the Logger variable:

```
 private readonly Logger _logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
```

Use it in the constructor of your class like:

```
(new NLogConfigurator()).ConfigureSeqBufferTarget();
```

The activation of the configuration is done by the class itself:

> LogManager.Configuration = config;

Here is the NLogConfigurator. I got it mainly from [NLog API](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-API)

```
public class NLogConfigurator
{
    private readonly string _logFileNamePattern;
    private readonly string _logLayoutPattern;

    public NLogConfigurator(string logFileNamePattern)
    {
        _logFileNamePattern = logFileNamePattern;
    }

    public NLogConfigurator()
    {
        string addInName = this.GetType().Assembly.GetName().Name;
        _logFileNamePattern = "${specialfolder:folder=CommonApplicationData}/Company/zenon/${processname}_" + addInName  + ".log";

        /* Layout of LogMessages:
         * See: https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Layout-Renderers
         * ${callsite} - The call site (class name, method name and source information).
         * ${message} - The formatted log message.
         * ${onexception} - Only outputs the inner layout when exception has been defined for log message.
         */
        _logLayoutPattern = @"${callsite} ${message} ${onexception:Exception information\:${exception:format=type,message,method,StackTrace:maxInnerExceptionLevel=5:innerFormat=type,message,method,StackTrace}";
    }

    public void Configure()
    {
        // See: https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-API

        // Step 1. Create configuration object 
        var config = new LoggingConfiguration();

        // Step 2. Create targets and add them to the configuration
        // See http://sentinel.codeplex.com/ for a log viewer 
        var viewerTarget = new NLogViewerTarget();
        config.AddTarget("viewer", viewerTarget);

        var fileTarget = new FileTarget();
        config.AddTarget("file", fileTarget);

        // Step 3. Set target properties 
        viewerTarget.Layout = _logLayoutPattern;
        viewerTarget.Address = "udp://127.0.0.1:9999";
        fileTarget.FileName = _logFileNamePattern;
        fileTarget.Layout = _logLayoutPattern;

        // Step 4. Define rules
        var rule1 = new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Debug, viewerTarget);
        config.LoggingRules.Add(rule1);

        var rule2 = new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Debug, fileTarget);
        config.LoggingRules.Add(rule2);

        // Step 5. Activate the configuration
        LogManager.Configuration = config;
    }


    public void ConfigureUDPTarget()
    {
        ConfigureUDPTarget(LogLevel.Debug);
    }

    public void ConfigureUDPTarget(LogLevel level, string ip = "udp://127.0.0.1:9999")
    {
        // See: https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-API

        // Step 1. Create configuration object 
        var config = new LoggingConfiguration();

        // Step 2. Create targets and add them to the configuration
        // See http://sentinel.codeplex.com/ for a log viewer 
        var viewerTarget = GetNLogViewerTarget(ip);

        var fileTarget = new FileTarget();
        config.AddTarget("file", fileTarget);

        // Step 3. Set target properties 
        fileTarget.FileName = _logFileNamePattern;
        fileTarget.Layout = _logLayoutPattern;

        // Step 4. Define rules
        var rule1 = new LoggingRule("*", level, viewerTarget);
        config.LoggingRules.Add(rule1);

        var rule2 = new LoggingRule("*", level, fileTarget);
        config.LoggingRules.Add(rule2);

        // Step 5. Activate the configuration
        LogManager.Configuration = config;
    }

    public void ConfigureSeqBufferTarget(LogLevel level, 
        string url = "http://localhost:5341", 
        string apiKey = "",
        int bufferSize= 1000,
        int flushTimeout= 2000)
    {
        // See: https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-API

        // Step 1. Create configuration object 
        var config = new LoggingConfiguration();
        var seqTarget = GetSeqTarget(url, apiKey);

        var bufferWrapper = new BufferingTargetWrapper
        {
            Name = "seq",
            BufferSize = bufferSize,
            FlushTimeout = flushTimeout,
            WrappedTarget = seqTarget
        };

        config.AddTarget(bufferWrapper);

        // Step 4. Define rules
        var rule1 = new LoggingRule("*", level, bufferWrapper);
        config.LoggingRules.Add(rule1);

        // Step 5. Activate the configuration
        LogManager.Configuration = config;
    }

    private Target GetNLogViewerTarget(string ip = "udp://127.0.0.1:9999")
    {
        return new NLogViewerTarget
        {
            Address = ip,
            Layout = _logLayoutPattern
        };
    }

    private Target GetSeqTarget(string url = "http://localhost:5341", string apiKey="")
    {
        return new SeqTarget
        {
            ServerUrl = url,
            ApiKey = apiKey
        };
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks a lot! i used the buttom part of the code, and it works great :)